# Como elimino una pagina intermedia del historial del browser?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una pagina A que llama a B pero indirectamente, primero llama a Ruedita.html que en el evento DOMContentLoaded llama a B mientras muestra un spinner.
¿El tema es como hago para que cuando B vuelva para atrás aparezca A y no Ruedita?

En la pagina A uso:

```
location.href = "/Ruedita.html"
```

En el evento load de Ruedita, mientras muestra un spinner:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        location.href = "/B";
    });
```

Finalmente se muestra B.
Pero cuando quiero volver para atras, aparece de nuevo Ruedita que vuelve a llamar a B, cuando debo volver a A.
No encuentro como eliminar la pagina de espera del historial.
Gracias.

Comment: Agregué al evento DOMContentLoaded:

    history.replaceState( null, null,"/B" );
pero no me queda claro.